# Angular2 split component into service and add AuthGuard

Tags: typescript, angular

I am using  `Auth0` and `angular2-jwt`for login, and i'm trying to implement CanActivate to block routes when user is logged in.
I have implemented the login code into the navbar.component, and trying to figure out how to make it more modular. I have some examples with services, but none of them match this case, so that's why i came here.

So i think there is 2 steps to make:

1. Implement AuthGuard to block routes.
2. Split this component into a service so it can send instructions to the AuthGuard to block or allow routes depending if the user is logged or not.

I am hoping someone will give me a solution and i can learn from it.
Thank you.

> Navbar.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, CanActivate  } from '@angular/router';
import {tokenNotExpired, JwtHelper} from 'angular2-jwt';

declare var Auth0Lock;

@Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
   selector: 'navbar',
   template : `
    <button *ngIf="!loggedIn()" (click)="login()">Login</button>
    <button *ngIf="loggedIn()" (click)="logout()">Logout</button>

    <a *ngIf="loggedIn()" [routerLink]="['/users']">Users</a>

   <button *ngIf="!loggedIn()" (click)="login()" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button>
   <button *ngIf="loggedIn()" (click)="logout()" class="btn btn-default">Logout</button>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES] 
})

export class NavbarComponent{
  lock = new Auth0Lock('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','yyyyyyyyyyyyyy')
  jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
  location: Location;
  profile : any;

constructor(){
  this.profile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
}

login(){
 var self = this;
 this.lock.show((err: string, profile: string, id_token: string) =>{
   if (err){
     throw new Error(err);
   }

   localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
   localStorage.setItem('id_token', id_token);  

     self.loggedIn();
 });
}

logout(){
  localStorage.removeItem('profile');
  localStorage.removeItem('id_token');

  this.loggedIn();
}

loggedIn(){
  return tokenNotExpired();
 }
 }
```

> auth.guard.ts:

```
import { CanActivate }    from '@angular/router';
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

> app.routes.ts

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import {UsersComponent} from './users/users.component';
import {AuthGuard} from './navbar/auth.guard';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
   { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },            
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes),
  AuthGuard
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fond the solution [Here](https://github.com/auth0-blog/angular2-authentication-sample):

> Auth.Guard.ts

```
import { CanActivate }    from '@angular/router';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate() {
      if (tokenNotExpired()) {
        return true;
      }
    }
}
```